# Is Service Worker supposed to install itself on every page reload or when navigating to a different page?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I am developing PWA. I am not quite clear, is service worker supposed to install on every page reload or if I navigate to a different page? It is doing that in my app? I got many files that are being cached in install event, looks that now it is doing that on every page reload.

If that is not what should be happening, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: No, it only installs once (if not specifically reinstalled), and is used on the pages you define on installation time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was that I left the issue was that I had the Update on reload checked in chrome dev tools, under Application -> Service Worker :)